# Make Bootstrap Collapse button and content position fixed

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Trying to position the button that triggers the bootstrap collapse in a fixed position so it is always visible when the user is scrolling on the page. However the position of the content that is shown when the button is clicked does not change with the button position. How do I show the collapsed content in the same default collapse format after changing the button position?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button style="position: fixed; top: 50% ;left: 50%", class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#butcollapse" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="butcollapse">
    +
  </button>
  
<div class="collapse" id="butcollapse">
  <div class="card card-body">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button style="position: fixed; top: 50% ;left: 50%", class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#butcollapse" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="butcollapse">
    +
  </button>
  
<div style="position: fixed; top: 75% ;left: 50%;" class="collapse" id="butcollapse">
  <div class="card card-body">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```